# Make HTML anchor to a new window in a strict docktype

Tags: html, anchor, xhtml-1.0-strict

We use "target" attribute of the  tag to specify the target location of the link.

But "target" attribute cannot be used in strict doctype (I referred this at http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp). So what is the solution if we use strict doctype?

Comment: Does anyone know WHY the "target" attribute is not a part of the strict DOCTYPE? Personally I prefer HTML5 which still has this attribute, but I'm just curious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, JavaScript.

The strict doctype is loosely considered to be "strictly document content" and not behaviour, which the target attribute defines.  It assumes the user will decide and have complete control over how links are opened in their browser.

The solution is to use JavaScript to define how links open.  You might use a class or other attribute to have a JS library to force them to open in a new window:

```
<a href="test.php" rel="external">my link</a>
```

So your script might look like this:

```
function externalLinks() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        if (anchor.getAttribute("href") &&
        anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "external")
        anchor.target = "_blank";
    }
}
window.onload = externalLinks;
```

This is even easier in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[rel=external]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: +1 for 1st paragraph. We may add that it is not obvious to the user how a link using the target attribute will behave when it is activated. Therefore - to be pure and clean - the script you propose should contain a hint that the page will open in a new window - otherwise you just "convert" a strict page into a transitional page post-load - meaning the DTD insinuates a strict doc while the behaviour is of a transitional ... slicing hairs?

Answer (score 2):

Either use the transitional doctype, which does allow `target`, or if you want to open a new window, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

window.open() is the programmatic way to open a new tab if you cannot rely on the default anchor behavior.  However, this will get intercepted by many pop-up blockers.  Consider an in-document overlay. http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/unblockable-popup.phtml